# Why does tkinter GUI show an error unable to create widget frame 3 after running the app for the second time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working in a project that selects devices to update via OTa but in the second time I run tk GUI and run the line `messagebox.showinfo("Weidoss firmware update", "Select file")`, an error is shown:

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
unable to create widget ".!frame3"
  File "/home/debian/Desktop/nuevo/RTU_Virtual_MODBUS-main (1)/rtu_virtual_modbus/mod_firmware/firmware.py", line 96, in UpdateFirmware
    messagebox.showinfo("Weidoss firmware update", "Select file")
_tkinter.TclError: unable to create widget ".!frame3"
```

Maybe it is related to an existing other instance of tk app running?

How can I correctly run the tk GUI?

Comment: How can we identify the issue without a [mre].

Comment: It's probably because you've destroyed the root window.